# Как вернуть select в первоначальное состояния не перезагружая страницу?

Tags: html, ajax, bootstrap, select

При использовании библиотеки bootstrap возникла проблема. У меня есть модальное окно для добавления пользователей, там я использую выпадающее меню select:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="addUsers">
  <select name="userRol" class = "userRol">
     <option  class = "one"> - </option>
     <option  class = "client">Клиент</option>
     <option  class = "baer">Баер</option>
  </select></div>
```

Когда я все данные выбираю и закрываю модальное окно у меня с помощью метода .load перезагружается часть модального окна:

```
$('#addUserModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $("#addUsers").load(" #addUsers");
 })
```

для того что бы все select вернулись в первоначальное состояние. Но когда я закрываю модальное окно и перезагружается часть его, перестает работать следующий код:

```
$('.client').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        data : {
            action : 'getInformUsersJsonClient'
        },
        success : function(dataJson){
            AddUsersList.onAjaxDone(dataJson);
        }
    });
});
```

хотя до перезагрузки все нормально работало.

В данном случае два вопроса:

1. Может кто то знает как вернуть select в первоначальное состояния по другому, не перезагружая страницу или часть ее?
2. Почему после перезагрузки перестает работать `$('.client').click`?

P.S.: через консоль срабатывает команды с `$('.client')`, но когда в отладчике смотрю, то оно не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2. При загрузке страницы вы с помощью `$('.client').click(fun)` создаете слушателя который отслеживает нажатие на элементы с классом `client`, после того как вы перезагружаете часть модального окна слушатель падает.

Поправить это можно создавая нового слушателя(после перезагрузки) или же html элементу добавить атрибут `onclick`, который будет вызывать необходимый метод:

html

```
<option onclick="fun();"  class = "client">Клиент</option>
```

js

```
var fun = function(){
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        data : {
            action : 'getInformUsersJsonClient'
        },
        success : function(dataJson){
            AddUsersList.onAjaxDone(dataJson);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Да этот метод мне помог, большое спасибо за объяснение.

Comment: @Casper если вы используете атрибут "onclick" в html, не забудьте убрать добавления слушателя из js ( $('.client').click(fun) ).

Comment: Да конечно я это уже сделал)) спасибо большое)

Answer (score 0):

А вот так?

```
$('body').on('click', '.client', function(){
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        data : {
            action : 'getInformUsersJsonClient'
        },
        success : function(dataJson){
            AddUsersList.onAjaxDone(dataJson);
        }
    });
});
```

Если начальное состояние select - это когда ничего не выбрано, то сбросить select, например, так:

`$('select').prop('selectedIndex',0);`

Правильнее вернуть select, чем делать http-запрос.